# How to save a calculation to a variable using variables that have not been defined yet?

Tags: r, calculation, nse

Let's say I have a script, where I have a calculation like this:

```
calculation = c(
                a*b + 
                c*d + 
                e*f
                )
```

And then in another script I want to call that calculation using the source command.

I get an error saying "Object 'a' not found". What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I don't want to make a function, because this specific calculation is used as input in a complex program in r (apollo) - the input specifies a utility function in a logit regression.

Comment: Also note that "c" is a function to combine elements. You should avoid trying to use c as a variable.

Comment: Ah yes, luckily I didn't use c like that in my real code.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture your expression using `expression()`, then when you're ready, evaluate using `eval()`:

```
calculation <- expression(a*b + d*e + f*g)

a <- 1
b <- 2
d <- 3
e <- 4
f <- 5
g <- 6

eval(calculation)
# 44
```

Comment: Is there no way to make it return 

a * b + d * e + f * g 

when you call "calculation"?

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to do. You said in your question “I don't want to make a function,” but you’re asking to “return” something when you “call” it, which certainly sounds like a function. Please edit your original question to include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805) to make it clearer what you want, including code showing how you want to use `calculation`, an example of what the result should look like, and any example data needed to run the code.